# wordpress get meta value by meta key

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, meta-query

How to get the meta value by meta key

I want to get the value by the meta key.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'picture_upload_1'
);
$dbResult = new WP_Query($args);

var_dump($dbResult);
```

but I am not receiving the meta value

Comment: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: thank you, but as mentioned in the question. i need to get the meta value by the meta key. I do not have the post id!

Comment: if you don't have the post ID, how do you know which meta value you're looking for if multiple posts have that key associated with them? what do you plan on doing with the meta values?

Comment: im writing a plugin, it has a custom post type and shortcode that accepts a parameter. When user saves the custom post, i store the key as slideshow_1 , the 1 will be random unique key, When user uses the shortcode [images id=1] , i will append 1 to slideshow_ and run a query, to get its meta value which has the image path

Comment: that doesn't answer either of my questions.

Comment: there wont be multiple post having the same key, the key will be unique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WP_Query` selects posts and not meta value that is way you are not getting the value.
You can use the returned post ID to get the value something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_key' => 'picture_upload_1'
);
$dbResult = new WP_Query($args);
global $post;
if ($dbResult->have_posts()){
   $dbResult->the_post();
   $value = get_post_meta($post->ID,'picture_upload_1',true);
}
```

which will get the meta value of the last post published which has a custom field named `picture_upload_1`

another thing you can do is create a query your self , something like:

```
 global $wpdb;
 $value = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s LIMIT 1" , $meta_key) );
```

Comment: this is super but why do we have to do global $post and  $dbResult->the_post(); and why the post_content is empty when we use $dbResult->get_posts(); function

Answer (score 0):

Get all values of meta_key anywhere:

```
global $wpdb;
$meta_key = 'picture_upload_1';

$data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s", $meta_key) , ARRAY_N  );

$result = [];
foreach($data as $array){
    $result[] = $array[0];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Why are you running over that array again?

Comment: Because the original array has nested  array (multidimensional array)

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider storing the value in the `wp_options` table instead of the `wp_postmetas`.

So you could use `get_option` with your custom key to set and retrieve your value.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/